# quagga barcode not detected big barcode

Tags: barcode, quagga

I am using quagga barcode library in HTML to scan barcode it works perfectly fine for small barcode but for big barcode it not works it gives me different value on scan and also sometimes it not even detect the big barcode

```
Quagga.init({
    inputStream: {
        name: 'Live',
        type: 'LiveStream',
        target: cameraPreview,
    },
    decoder: {
        readers: ['code_128_reader','ean_reader', 'ean_8_reader', 'code_39_reader', 'code_39_vin_reader', 'codabar_reader', 'upc_reader', 'upc_e_reader']
    }
}, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    Quagga.initialized = true;
    Quagga.start();
});
```